# How to design the exception classes when interfaces and inheritance are present

Tags: c#

The question goes as follows, let's say I want to read **SomeImportantData** from some files. SomeImportantData can be found in text files and also in XML files so I will make a simple interface.

```
public interface SIDReader
{
   void Open();
   string GetSID();
   void Close();
}


public class TextSIDReader : SIDReader
{
   ... override methods with text specific parsing
}

public class XmlSIDReader: SIDReader
{
   ... override methods with xmlspecific parsing
}
```

The problem is with throwing the exceptions that can arise let's say when we use the Open() method. In this method, the text reader approach would simply open the file in memory while the XML version would firstly check that the file is a valid XML file, do some other checks  and load it in a tree. How would the exceptions be designed for such a case ? Should there be some generic exceptions that may not apply for both cases or should there be some specific exceptions? Let me make it more clear with a little code:

```
  SIDReader reader = new XmlSIDReader();
  try
  {
     reader.Open();
  } // generic exceptions
  catch(ParsingException)   // a exception that may arise only for the XML version, let's say when loading the tree    
  { 
      // tell the user you have a parsing exception so the file might be corrupt 
  }
  catch(DataIntegrityException) // again something specific for XML's
```

or something more specific

```
  SIDReader reader = new XmlSIDReader();
  try
  {
     reader.Open();
  } // specific exceptions
  catch(XmlTreeLoadException)      
  { 
      // tell the user you have a tree loading exception so the file might be corrupt 
  }
  catch(TextReaderException) // something specific for text parsers
```

I know that this might sound like a simply naming problem but for the generic exceptions, if you want to report to the user that the xml tree is invalid, in the catch clause for the ParsingException you have to check what parser is been used and format the error message accordingly ("Xml data is not valid") and in this case for the text reader there is nothing to report. If you use specific exceptions you know exactly what to report because you already know what failed but you leak the abstraction all over the place.

What method is better or what are the alternatives? The language is C# but this is a pretty general question.

Comment: I just wish to highlight that this question asks *"How to Design?"* instead of *"How to Code?"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your question rephrased:

> *What is the right level of abstraction at which my code should throw the Exceptions?*

---

### The apt answer:

> *The **Exception's level of abstraction should be consistent with the interface abstraction** of the routine in which the exceptional
>   situation has occurred.*

In your case, you show hints of thinking in the right direction when you say that it is a *naming problem*. Pretty close... it's an *abstraction problem*.

Therefore,

- If someone is working at the level of your interface `SIDReader` and something exceptional happened in the `Open()`, the Exception should say that it failed to read from the SIDReader and should have *InnerException* from the actual class that implemented this `SIDReader` interface, i.e. either `XmlSIDReader` or `TextSIDReader`.
- If the person is working at the level of your `XmlSIDReader` and something exceptional happened in the `Open()` in this class, then the Exception's message should say that it failed to open an Xml file.. blah blah blah.
- If the person is working at the level of your `TestSIDReader` and something exceptional happened in the `Open()` in this class, then the Exception's message should say that it failed to open the text file and so on.

This understanding can be trickled down further to various other methods as well. For example if even within the `Open()` some other method is called and the exceptional thing took place there, then this method should have its own Exception thrown up telling exactly what happened at *it's own level*. That Exception can be wrapped up by the `Open()` and that can be further wrapped up by the actual class in which this `Open()` is implemented.

---

### Consider too that...

1. You should always consider full set of *error handling techniques*:

   1. handling the error locally;
   2. propagating the error by using an *error-code*;
   3. logging debug information to a file;
   4. shutting down the system;
   5. or using some other approach.
2. Handling errors with exceptions just because your language provides exception handling is a classic example of [programming *in* a language vs programming *into* a language](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2008/04/23/programming-quot-in-quot-a-language-vs-programming-quot-into-quot-a-language/), and;
3. *"Sometimes, the best response to a serious run-time error is to release all acquired resources and abort"* - Bjarne Stroustrup.

---

*This answer is inspired from Steve-McConnell's legendary book - **Code Complete 2***

Comment: So you say that XmlSIDReader and TestSIDReader should throw their own specific exceptions, wrap them in a more higher level abstraction and throw again keeping the original exception as inner exception? But then, higher, I must interrogate for the inner exception type because that gives me the idea of what happened and not the exceptions message. Doesn't that break a little the design(leaking abstraction) ? And catching, wrapping and re throwing again doesn't translate more to a error codes mindset? Also, aren't the 2 classes on the same level as the SIDReader? They are just it's ploymorphs.

Comment: 1) XmlSIDReader and TestSIDReader should throw their own specific exceptions, if it makes sense in your application. But *if you do choose them to throw the exceptions, the details mentioned in the abstraction should be at the method's level,* 2) If you think you are breaking the abstraction by doing that, then don't do it. Instead catch the exception and re-write it at the level of abstraction you want and throw it further up. 3) The two classes are at the same level, the interface is not. These classes are not the interface's polymorphs. (Contd...)

Comment: (continuation) . There comes my problem from. Should their exceptions be specific or general to the interface? You say that the Exceptions should be consistent with the current level of abstraction. At the interface level I will have a exception that says that the file couldn't be opened but I am pretty sure the user wants to know that the xml(going specific) file is corrupted and not just that the file could not be opened. I am a former C++ programmer trying to really get the exception mindset that's why the many questions. Thanks

Comment: Rather, implementing the interface is just a way of these classes showing that they have something in common. You can't compare the *level* of classes with interface. It's like comparing qualitative thing with a quantitative thing.

Comment: @user2436426: Yes, I get the point you are trying to make. Let's say you have a reader object and an exception occurs. What this exception will tell will be dependent on the *type* of the reader. If the reader's type is general - i.e. type of interface - then the info should be general. If the reader's type is specific - i.e. XmlSIDReader or TestSIDReader type - then the exception's info should be specific to the actual type.

Comment: The type is always specific, the interface is just a pointer to it's concrete (common behavior )implementation. That's the problem, you will use the one of the classes in the space of the interface. If they throw something specific you will have to deal with specific details in a more general space. If you make the implementations throw general exceptions for the interface then some exceptions will not make sense for some of the implementations. Also, if the exceptions will be specific how will you have interface specific info?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90064/discussion-between-user2436426-and-displayname).

Comment: Whether your `reader` is defined as `new XmlSIDReader()` or as `new TextSIDReader()` or received in a method as `SIDReader` (ideally) determines the level of abstraction at which the Exception should be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject and exception class into each of the child classes, lets say for the TextSIDReader class

```
public interface IExceptionHandler
{
    void HandleException(Exception exception);
}

public class TextSIDExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public void HandleException(Exception exception)
    {
        //do whatever you want with the exception, you can try to cast it to specific exception type and act according type
    }
}

public interface SIDReader
{
   void Open();
   string GetSID();
   void Close();
}

public class TextSIDReader : SIDReader
{
   private IExceptionHandler _exceptionHandler;

    public void TextSIDReader(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler)
    {
        _exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _exceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }

    public string GetSID()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the problem with your solution is that it mixes high level decisions with lower level details. The SIDReader class should not handle the exceptions, that is something that should be taken care at a higher level, a application level, this class should only parse for the needed information.  Also catching the general Exception class is not a good idea, I need then to interrogate for the type with things like "is instance of" and that generally smells as bad design. My question was more how the exceptions should be designed. Anyway, thanks for the effort and your thoughts.

Comment: if you are targeting application level you should read about aspect oriented programming,an example is mvc action filters and exception filters were the filter is wrapping every action and handling their exceptions.